# Can a preposition be put before a noun phrase that expresses a period of time?

Tags: prepositions, idioms

> He's worked hard **all year**.

When I speak the sentence in Korean, ‘all year’ can select a postposition or be used alone. For English, is this sentence, ‘He’s worked hard for[during] all year,’ proper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't normally use a preposition with *all year*, or *all* any period of time:

> <sup>✲</sup>He's worked hard for all week.

We *may* however use a preposition and a determiner with *whole PERIOD* or *entire PERIOD*:

> He's worked hard the whole year. *OR* He's worked hard for the whole year.
>   He worked hard that entire week. *OR* He worked hard for that entire week.

And if you interpose a determiner after *all*, a preposition is acceptable:

> He's worked hard all this year. *OR* He's worked hard for all this year.

I have no idea why this is so. It just is.

Comment: "He's worked hard for all this year" sounds really odd to me.

Comment: @Matt Frankly, a little to me, too; but not dead wrong like the others; and **a)** For all *that* year and **b)** the inversion *For all this year he's worked hard* ***don't*** sound odd, at least to me; so I came down on the side of acceptability.

Comment: I can't quite explain why, but I can make it sound right *or* wrong in my head.

Comment: @snailplane I think I've pinned down the ambivalence in [NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+all+this+year%2Cfor+all+these+years%2Cfor+all+those+years&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=): it's very rare in the singular, but common, and increasingly so, in the plural 'for all these years', 'for all those years'